# How to remove the default sort function from a TreeSortable?

Tags: python, c, sorting, treeview

The official Gtk3 C documentation for the GtkTreeSortable set_default_func states that setting the sort function to a `Null` value would remove the default sort function and thus a treeview once the sort is defined can never go to an unsorted state:

- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkTreeSortable.html#gtk-tree-sortable-set-default-sort-func

> If sort_func is NULL, then there will be no default comparison
>   function. This means that once the model has been sorted, it can't go
>   back to the default state.

That is exactly what I want to do with my TreeView.  I have defined my own sort-function with `set_sort_func` and the model is correctly sorted.

What I'm trying to do is interpret the C instructions for Python.

This is the snippet of python code I'm using:

```
self.artist_manager.model.store.set_default_sort_func(sort_func=None, user_data=None)
```

where `self.artist_manager.model.store` points to a Gtk.TreeModelSort on my Gtk.TreeStore

i.e. I've interpreted "sort_func is NULL" in the official documentation is be the same as `None` in python.

However I'm getting this error:

```
File "/home/dad/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_artistview.py", line 765, in initialise
    self.artist_manager.model.store.set_default_sort_func(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 915, in set_default_sort_func
    super(TreeSortable, self).set_default_sort_func(sort_func, user_data)
TypeError: Argument 1 does not allow None as a value
```

I've checked the official GTK documentation back to version 3.2 and all the instructions for `set_default_sort_func` doesnt really change.

I've also used the function `has_default_sort_func` and this returns `True` telling me that I have indeed got a default sort function...

Thus to my question - I'm obviously interpreting the C to python conversion incorrectly - how can I remove the default sort function through python?

Comment: no - I had to code around this with my own sorting function.  Would still love to know if this is still possible though :/

Answer (score 1):

7 years later while trying to revive an old Python 2.7 PyGTK app I encounter the same error message and end up here.  I have no idea if this has changed in the intervening years but I did find a solution so, in case anyone else ends up here.

I had this (which had been working in pygtk):

```py
model = Gtk.TreeStore(object)
model.set_default_sort_func(None)
```

Which raised the same error you mention even though the PyGobject API reference seemed to [suggest it should work](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSortable.html#Gtk.TreeSortable.set_default_sort_func). ("*If `sort_func` is `None`, then there will be no default comparison function.*").
I ended up replaced the `set_default_sort_func` line with:

```py
model.set_sort_column_id(Gtk.TREE_SORTABLE_UNSORTED_SORT_COLUMN_ID, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)
```

Now `has_default_sort_func` returns `False`

from the PyGObject API Reference for [set_sort_column_id(](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSortable.html#Gtk.TreeSortable.set_sort_column_id)):

> may either be a regular column id, or one of the following special
> values:
>
> - Gtk.TREE_SORTABLE_DEFAULT_SORT_COLUMN_ID: the default sort function will be used, if it is set
> - Gtk.TREE_SORTABLE_UNSORTED_SORT_COLUMN_ID: no sorting will occur